# Programatically edit hyperlinks inside a PDF

Tags: linux, node.js, shell, pdf

I am trying to find a way to programatically edit the links inside an already generated PDF. My stack is just Node.js for now but I am open to any kind of tech that you believe can do this. Doing some searches around this on stackoverflow and other websites lead me to things like [Debenu's PDF Library](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/) but this is not an opensource solution and it is a .NET solution.

Doing a `strings` on one of my own PDFs shows me this kind of strings :

```
# strings mypdf.pdf | grep tfoureur -C2
--
61 0 obj
<</IsMap false/S/URI/URI(http://stack.im/tfoureur)>>
endobj
--
```

I do not know if it would be a clean solution to just walk the binary searching for these strings and edit them in place. I also do not know if this is the standard format and it would work all the time or not.

Do you recommend a particular approach ?

Comment: In-place editing may not be a good idea, as a PDF contains *indexed data*. See the official specification (the link is on [tag:pdf] tag).

Comment: Hmm.. I get your point, I will go through the specs, but there must be a clean way somehow to programatically do so

Comment: But of course there is. The correct way is to dismantle the PDF into its constituent objects, change only the ones you want, and reconstruct the PDF.

Comment: Alright, I'll do some more research on the inner workings of the PDF format and the opensource tools that could help me do so. I'll post the results of my research here, and might also open a bounty for this question. Thanks!